# Verify the HTTP_REFERER if is set then pass the information

Tags: php, session, session-variables, http-referer

I have a form and I need to verify if the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is complemented, if yes then pass the `HTTP_REFERER` after submit in database. The problem is that when you submit the form the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` = location where the form is hosted, I need the `HTTP_REFERER` from where the user comes to the form.
I tried this:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['REFERER'])){
    $_SESSION['REFERER'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

But the `$_SESSION['REFERER']` will be the location where the form is hosted.

Comment: `verify` and `HTTP Referrer` cannot get along. If you are using privacy mode with the browser, the referrer might be removed. You will have legit  requests without referrer.

Comment: Did you wrote session_start() top of the page which you setting session ? If not session won't work.

Comment: I have `session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines on your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="referrer" value="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ?>">
```

This way the user can post this data to you. I suppose that you're intending this to return the user to the page they were visiting after they log in, just bear two things in mind:

- Malicious users can modify the referrer themselves, so you need to be careful what the user is sending to avoid your server being attacked.
- Malicious users can manipulate the referrer of other people.

You need to check that your referrer is an URL, and you need to check that it's source is within your own domain.

Afterwards you can just read the data from your form with

```
<?php $originalreferrer = $_POST['referrer']? $_POST['referrer'] : 'default_value';
```

Comment: I can't use hidden because it can be modified and is not for a login. I need to use session to store that info but It seems I can't store the referrer when the user comes to the form

Comment: Your example introduces XSS vulnerability

Comment: @DanFromGermany That is why I pointed out that it's not perfect, and that he needed to make sure that everything was checked and double checked.

Comment: @NeculaiAndrei You should really consider a completely different approach to your application if the danger of a user manipulating a single field can hurt your application. Just like an hidden input, the referrer can be modified easily. Your approach is insecure either way.